# react-hook-form Modifying input and throwing custom error as user types with

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

What I am trying to do is make it so that when a user types into the email field I run my `makeLowerCase` function. Which should :

1. throw a hook-form error.message on the email field, if the current email input has a capital in it
2. convert the value of that input to all lowercase so the user can't input a capital

## [Full code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-thunder-yzuv2n?file=/src/App.tsx)

### function:

```js
function makeLowerCase() {
    let email = getValues("email");

    // test if email contains uppercase letters
    if (/[A-Z]/.test(email)) {
      setError(
        "email",
        {
          type: "manual",
          message: "Email must be lowercase",
        },
        { shouldFocus: true }
      );
    }

    setValue("email", email.toLowerCase());
  }
```

### Form:

```js
 <main className="container">
        <h1 className="text-center">Password Reset</h1>
        <section className="mt-4 row justify-content-center">
          <form
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(formSubmit)}
            className="p-4 border rounded shadown form-group"
          >
            <label>Email </label>
            <input
              className="mb-2 form-control"
              {...(register("email"),
              {
                onChange: () => {
                  makeLowerCase();
                },
              })}
              placeholder="email"
            />
            <small className="text-danger">
              {formState.errors.email?.message}
            </small>
            <br />
            <label>Password </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              className="mb-2 form-control"
              {...register("password")}
              placeholder="new password"
            />
            <small className="text-danger">
              {formState.errors.password?.message}
            </small>
            <br />
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              className="mb-2 form-control"
              {...register("confirmPassword")}
              placeholder="confirm new password"
            />
            <small className="text-danger">
              {formState.errors.confirmPassword?.message}
            </small>
            <br />
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Reset Password
            </button>

            <Link className="btn btn-secondary ml-2" to={`/login`}>
              Or click here to login
            </Link>
          </form>
        </section>
      </main>
```

#### Problems I have encountered:

1. `setValueAs` attribute on the input works after validation so user inputs capitals without knowing they will be converted
2. `value` attribute is not dynamic so it is useless
3. `onChange` attribute is currently not working as expexted
4. If the input is not updated before validation it will error because its `.email()` validator only wants lowercase